# illegalStateException: Failed to connect service esxception when using toPS operation in adobe livecycle

Tags: livecycle

I'm using toPShttp://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/workbenchHelp/help.htm?content=000555.html operation that is avilable to adobe livecycle, though it is deprecated we have been using it for years and suddenly it started throwing the below exception.

```
ALC-DSC-003-000: com.adobe.idp.dsc.DSCInvocationException: Invocation error.
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.component.impl.DefaultPOJOInvokerImpl.invoke(DefaultPOJOInvokerImpl.java:152)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvocationInterceptor.intercept(InvocationInterceptor.java:140)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.DocumentPassivationInterceptor.intercept(DocumentPassivationInterceptor.java:53)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(TransactionInterceptor.java:74)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EjbTransactionBMTAdapterBean.doBMT(EjbTransactionBMTAdapterBean.java:197)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EJSLocalStatelessEjbTransactionBMTAdapter_3af08fdf.doBMT(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.EjbTransactionProvider.execute(EjbTransactionProvider.java:95)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionInterceptor.java:72)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvocationStrategyInterceptor.intercept(InvocationStrategyInterceptor.java:55)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvalidStateInterceptor.intercept(InvalidStateInterceptor.java:37)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.AuthorizationInterceptor.intercept(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:188)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.JMXInterceptor.intercept(JMXInterceptor.java:48)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.engine.impl.ServiceEngineImpl.invoke(ServiceEngineImpl.java:115)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.routing.Router.routeRequest(Router.java:129)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.base.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:93)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.vm.VMMessageDispatcher.doSend(VMMessageDispatcher.java:209)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.base.AbstractMessageDispatcher.send(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:66)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.clientsdk.ServiceClient.invoke(ServiceClient.java:208)
at com.adobe.workflow.engine.PEUtil.invokeAction(PEUtil.java:886)
at com.adobe.idp.workflow.dsc.invoker.WorkflowDSCInvoker.transientInvoke(WorkflowDSCInvoker.java:347)
at com.adobe.idp.workflow.dsc.invoker.WorkflowDSCInvoker.invoke(WorkflowDSCInvoker.java:158)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvocationInterceptor.intercept(InvocationInterceptor.java:140)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.DocumentPassivationInterceptor.intercept(DocumentPassivationInterceptor.java:53)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(TransactionInterceptor.java:74)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.execute(EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.java:357)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.doRequiresNew(EjbTransactionCMTAdapterBean.java:299)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EJSLocalStatelessEjbTransactionCMTAdapter_caf58c4f.doRequiresNew(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.EjbTransactionProvider.execute(EjbTransactionProvider.java:143)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.intercept(TransactionInterceptor.java:72)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvocationStrategyInterceptor.intercept(InvocationStrategyInterceptor.java:55)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.InvalidStateInterceptor.intercept(InvalidStateInterceptor.java:37)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.AuthorizationInterceptor.intercept(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:188)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.JMXInterceptor.intercept(JMXInterceptor.java:48)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.interceptor.impl.RequestInterceptorChainImpl.proceed(RequestInterceptorChainImpl.java:60)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.engine.impl.ServiceEngineImpl.invoke(ServiceEngineImpl.java:115)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.routing.Router.routeRequest(Router.java:129)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.base.AbstractMessageReceiver.invoke(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:329)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.soap.axis.sdk.SoapSdkEndpoint.invokeCall(SoapSdkEndpoint.java:139)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.soap.axis.sdk.SoapSdkEndpoint.invoke(SoapSdkEndpoint.java:81)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor255.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.provider.impl.soap.axis.InvocationFilter.doFilter(InvocationFilter.java:43)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.adobe.idp.um.auth.filter.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:41)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:895)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:183)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:557)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:607)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:984)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1069)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
 Caused by: com.adobe.livecycle.convertpdfservice.exception.ConvertPdfException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection to failed service.
at com.adobe.convertpdf.ConvertPdfBmcWrapper.convertPdftoPs(ConvertPdfBmcWrapper.java:213)
at com.adobe.convertpdf.ConvertPdfServer.convertPdftoPs(ConvertPdfServer.java:85)
at com.adobe.convertpdf.docservice.ConvertPdfServiceImpl.toPS2InTxn(ConvertPdfServiceImpl.java:166)
at com.adobe.convertpdf.docservice.ConvertPdfServiceImpl.access$000(ConvertPdfServiceImpl.java:46)
at com.adobe.convertpdf.docservice.ConvertPdfServiceImpl$1.doInTransaction(ConvertPdfServiceImpl.java:139)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EjbTransactionBMTAdapterBean.doRequiresNew(EjbTransactionBMTAdapterBean.java:218)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.adapter.EJSLocalStatelessEjbTransactionBMTAdapter_3af08fdf.doRequiresNew(Unknown Source)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.ejb.EjbTransactionProvider.execute(EjbTransactionProvider.java:133)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.transaction.impl.DefaultTransactionTemplate.execute(DefaultTransactionTemplate.java:79)
at com.adobe.convertpdf.docservice.ConvertPdfServiceImpl.toPS2WithSMT(ConvertPdfServiceImpl.java:135)
at com.adobe.convertpdf.docservice.ConvertPdfServiceImpl.toPS2(ConvertPdfServiceImpl.java:125)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.adobe.idp.dsc.component.impl.DefaultPOJOInvokerImpl.invoke(DefaultPOJOInvokerImpl.java:118)
... 94 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection to failed service.
at com.adobe.convertpdf.ConvertPdfBmcWrapper.convertPdftoPs(ConvertPdfBmcWrapper.java:212)
... 109 more
```

I tried the same operation on a different Livecycle server and it works fine with no issues. There are enough memory and disk space. The other operation on the same server works fine with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it kept failing is for two reason. The reason was clearly mentioned on the WebSphere error log. Well actually there were two reasons.

1. Disk space was full
2. The adobe library is corrupted/ not deployed properly. There were some core files(libpdftops.so etc) missing under the bin directory //../adobe/alcClone1/ConvertPdfService/bin

Answer (score 0):

First off, please stop using this deprecated operation and update your code/orchestration to use the "toPS2" operation as outlined in the documentation:

> Note: This operation is deprecated in LiveCycle ES2 version 8.2. Use
>   the toPS2 operation instead. It is recommended that when you upgrade a
>   process, you change it to use the toPS2 operation.

Secondly, Illegal state can be due to a number of factors/reasons. It seems like service is unavailable for some reason:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection to failed service.
```

Recommendations:

1. Check in workbench/AdminUI if the service is deployed and active.
2. Reboot the application server and test again to see if that solves the problem.

Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Thanks,
Armaghan.